# Drupal 7 & PHP - display content if $form is any Content Type

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I need help creating an if statement that will print out a cancel button **only** in forms for nodes. Without an if statement the cancel button prints out on all forms, including site search forms. I tried using a '$form_id !=' but adding every form ID where I **don't** want the cancel button to be doesn't seem very intuitive. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php

/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function cancel_button_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Here is where I'm having trouble. What variable can 
  // I put that targets ANY content type?
  if ($form_id != 'search_block_form') {
    // Add a cancel button.
    $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Cancel'),
      '#access' => TRUE,
      '#weight' => 15,
      '#submit' => array('cancel_button_form_cancel', 'node_form_submit_build_node'),
      '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
    );
  }
}

/**
* Custom cancel button callback.
*/
function cancel_button_form_cancel($form, &$form_state) {
$url = $_GET['destination'] ? $_GET['destination'] : '';
drupal_goto($url);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, how are we supposed to know the form is "content type"? You must give us the $form array with all info if it contains anything that indicates its a "content type" form.

Comment: I'm...confused? This is just a simple module that I'm working on that will add a cancel button to any form. I want to make the cancel button appear only in forms for nodes (maybe that's better than saying "content types") using an if statement but I do not know what I can use (or how) to target just forms for nodes using said if statement. Sorry, you'll have to bear with me since I am not an experienced Drupal guy. Basically: if('what should I put here to target only forms for nodes?') { print out cancel button }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a node/content, the `$form` variable will have a node object. But if the form is not for/from node then it won't have the node object. You can check like this:

```
if(isset($form['#node'])) {
    // Your code goes here
}
```

Actually, I have a bit confusion about `$form['#node']` (:P). You can get it by debugging the `$form` or `$form_state` variable.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you Omar for the help and for being patient with me.